# Simplify a limit problem with the difference quotient $(g(x)-g(a))/(x-a)$ given $g(x) = -3x^2+8x+12$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify this limit problem using the difference quotient, but I am not sure how to cancel out the a,s since it is g(x) and not g(x+a).

Here is my work so far:
$$ \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\text{ given }g(x) = -3x^2+8x+12$$

$$= \frac{(-3x^2+8x+12) - (-3a^2+8a+12)}{x-a}$$

cancel out the $12$'s and now I factor out an $(x-a)$

$$= \frac{(x-a)(-3x+8)-(-3a+8)}{x-a}$$

now I try cancelling out the $(x-a)$ from both top and bottom, but that leaves me with $3a-3x$, the answer I get applying the power rule to the original function is $g'(x)= -6x+8$

so I am not sure how to work the algebra in this case, any advice?

Comment: 1st: if the limit says $x\to a$ the answer can't have any $x$. 2nd: check the factorization. After 12 is cancelled, you can factor for $x-a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{(-3x^2+8x+12) - (-3a^2+8a+12)}{x-a} = \frac{-3(x^2-a^2) + 8 (x-a)}{x-a}
$$
$$
= \frac{-3(x-a)(x+a)+8(x-a)}{x-a} = \frac{\Big(-3(x+a)+ 8 \Big)(x-a)}{x-a} = -3(x+a)+8
$$

Then let $x\to a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use that for any $x\ne a$ it is

$$\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=\frac{-3x^2+8x+12+3a^2-8a-12}{x-a}=\frac{-3x^2+8x+3a^2-8a}{x-a}\\=\frac{-3(x^2-a^2)+8(x-a)}{x-a}=\frac{-3(x-a)(x+a)}{x-a}+8=-3(x+a)+8$$